# Thread pool with Apps Script on Spreadsheet

Tags: multithreading, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Spreadsheet with internal AppsScript code which process each row of the sheet and perform an urlfetch with the row data. The url will provide a value which will be added to the values returned by each row processing..

For now the code is processing 1 row at a time with a simple `for`:

```
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
var range = sheet.getDataRange();

for(var i=1 ; i<range.getValues().length ; i++) {
   var payload = {
       // retrieve data from the row and make payload object
   };

   var options = {
      "method":"POST",
      "payload" : payload
   };

   var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://.......", options);
   var text = result.getContentText();

   // Save result for final processing
   // (with multi-thread function this value will be the return of the function)
}
```

Please note that this is only a simple example, in the real case the working function will be more complex (like 5-6 http calls, where the output of some of them are used as input to the next one, ...).

For the example let's say that there is a generic "function" which executes some sort of processing and provides a result as output.

In order to speed up the process, I'd like to try to implement some sort of "multi-thread" processing, so I can process multiple rows in the same time.
I already know that javascript does not offer a multi-thread handling, but I read about `WebWorker` which seems to create an async processing of a function.

My goal is to obtain some sort of ThreadPool (like 5 threads at a time) and send every row that need to be processed to the pool, obtaining as output the result of each function.

When all the rows finished the processing, a final action will be performed gathering all the results of each function.

So the capabilities I'm looking for are:

- managed "ThreadPool" where I can submit an N amount of tasks to be performed
- possibility to obtain a resulting value from each task processed by the pool
- possibility to determine that all the tasks has been processed, so a final "event" can be executed

I already see that there are some ready-to-use libraries like:

- https://www.hamsters.io/wiki#thread-pool
- http://threadsjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
- https://github.com/andywer/threadpool-js

but they work with NodeJS. Due to AppsScript nature, I need a more simplier approach, which is provided by native JS. Also, it seems that minified JS are not accepted by AppsScript editor, so I also need the "expanded" version.

Do you know a simple ThreadPool in JS where I can submit a function to be execute and I get back a Promise for the result?

Comment: If my understanding is correct, how about using [the fetchAll method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchAll(Object))? This was added at January 19, 2018. The fetchAll method is worked by the asynchronous processing.

Comment: @Tanaike The working function is more complex than a simple http call (there is payload manipulation, multiple http calls, ...). This is not a suitable for my case

Comment: I'm really sorry I couldn't help.

Comment: Why use Apps Script? You can host your multi-threaded code on a server using the language of your choice and simply dispatch the source material to it with your Apps Script function, then use the Sheets API to send data back (or write a webapp for the script project to handle the data coming back from a GET/POST request). The never-persistent nature of Apps Script will really mutilate your implementation of threading.

Comment: @tehhowch I'm using Apps Script simply because the application is already made and shared to users. So I do not want to twist users but only improve (if possibile, of course) the processing part.

Comment: @DevilingMaster as I said - dispatch the data to a server running code of your choice that supports threading as you desire, then send the processed data back to your spreadsheet